# Using Java's JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am trying to use Java's JOptionnPane module. Here is the code:

```
Object[] options = {"OK", "Cancel"};
JOptionPane.showInternalOptionDialog(null, "Your choice", "Division", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
```

`error: JOptionPane: parentComponent does not have a valid parent at...`

Comment: InternalOptionDialog needs a parent dialog. you could use showOptionDialog method.

Comment: vels4j: tnx that solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

JOptionPane.showInternalInputDialog is to be used with JDesktopPane/JInternalFrames only, where this is the JDesktopPane/JInternalFrames instance.

```
final JDesktopPane deskpane = new JDesktopPane();
...
String str=JOptionPane.showInternalInputDialog(deskpane, "Enter value");
```

If not used with either of the 2 above mentioned components it will not produce the correct output, in fact it will throw a Runtime Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: JOptionPane: parentComponent does not have a valid pa
```

Comment: I was asking about showInternalOptionDialog but the problem is similar. Its trowing an exception because no parent component is specified. Although it said that it can be set to null

Answer (score 1):

exception talking about uncorrectly user parameters, its value or their orders,

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class MyOptionPane {

    public MyOptionPane() {
        Icon errorIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");
        Object[] possibilities = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};
        Integer i = (Integer) JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
                null,  "ShowInputDialog", 
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,1,  errorIcon, possibilities, 0);
        Integer ii = (Integer) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Select number:\n\from JComboBox", "ShowInputDialog",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, errorIcon, possibilities, "Numbers");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyOptionPane mOP = new MyOptionPane();
            }
        });
    }
}
```